# Using ruby gsub to parse stock ticker

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have the following stock ticker string:

```
"NKE170217C00055000"
```

Using gsub, what would be the best way to grab from the ticker:

1. Company name (i.e. "NKE")
2. Date (i.e. "170217")
3. Type (i.e. "C")

Thank!

Comment: Do stock ticker symbols consist only of letters? Or are numbers allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the date is the first number with 6 digits, the company name is right before and the type is right after, you can use this Regexp :

```
/(\w+?)(\d{6})([a-z])\d+/i
```

Since you asked for `gsub` (which might not be the best solution here) :

```
"NKE170217C00055000".gsub(/(\w+?)(\d{6})([a-z])\d+/i,'Name : \1, Date : \2, Type : \3')
#=> "Name : NKE, Date : 170217, Type : C"
```